# How do I use multiple lines in the R command prompt

Tags: r

How do I use multiple lines of code in the R command prompt?

I want to write a for loop but the problems are the following lines:

```
res <- numeric(length = length(a))
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  res[i] <- a[i] + b[i]
}
```

So I would need 4 lines, but I am limited to 1 line with the command prompt

Comment: `{res <- numeric(length = length(a));for (i in seq_along(a)) {res[i] <- a[i] + b[i]}}`?

Comment: Do you mean the RStudio console or your terminal? In case of the console, you can use Shift+Enter, otherwise, I fully agree with @jay.sf

Comment: I don't under stand what the problem is. You should be able to just copy/paste that to the console or type it exactly how you see it. R will run each line as it's complete. The opening brace on the for line will let R know the statement isn't complete until it sees the closing brace. What exactly is the problem you are running in to?

Comment: Well didn't think that through. Anyway is { the method to use multiple lines in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `;`

```
x <- 1 + 2; x / 6
[1] 0.5
```